# How to expose docker container over internet using windows

Tags: docker, ip-address, router

I have configured my router to expose http 80 on my local machine ip address:
ie '192.168.0.79', and exposed both inbound and outbound ip address, including allowing through firewall. For the purpose of this example lets say its "200.200.200.200"

I have a node server running locally on this same ip address which works and I can see 'hello world' when I visit my exposed ip address, eg: 200.200.200.200 on my web browser. This works.

```js
import yargs from 'yargs';
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

const argv = yargs.argv;
const host = argv.host ;
const port = argv.port;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(port, host, function() {
  console.log('listening on ', host, ':', port);
});
```

when I stop the node server and instead run a docker container on the same ip address as follows:

```
docker run -p 192.168.0.79:80:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name myjenkins -v %cd%/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins
```

I can see this locally on my machine, but when trying to access it from external webbrowser, eg: "200.200.200.200" it simply returns - HTTP ERROR 504

Is there something else I need to expose via the docker container to make this visible online?

I'm having the same issue with an nginx image. So i'm convinced there is something missing in my docker arguments.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html/dist

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

```
docker build -t nginx_image .
docker run -p 192.168.0.79:80:8080 nginx_image
```

Comment: In some cases your ISP may block port 80 from being accessed externally

Comment: what is the value of `host`?

Comment: host is 192.168.0.79

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a return route issue. Log onto your docker container and see if you can ping 8.8.8.8. Also run netstat -r and see what the default route is. It should be the internal IP address of your firewall.

Comment: thanks. 
```docker exec -it myjenkins ping 8.8.8.8```
 returned perpetual - 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=40 ttl=37 time=14.9 ms. 

```

Comment: ```netstat -r``` returned  one of active routes: 192.168.0.79  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.79    281

Comment: Can you login to your firewall and ping 192.168.0.79 successfully from there?

Comment: It's a sky router. Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

ok so on much exhaustive research it seems there might be a problem with windows exposing these containers. Or it might be something more advanced regarding proxying this container to the outside.

My solution. Create a node server that proxys to the localhost on my machine.

## step 1 - get my ip address for this particular desktop computer on the ethernet

start > cmd

```
ipconfig 
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4 (Yours will be different. Which ever is connected to the internet):
...
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.79
```

## step 2 - configure router, sky or other, to expose this ip to the internet

- visit 192.168.0.2

```
user: admin
pass: sky
```

- > Advanced > Lan IP Setup > LAN TCP/IP Setup

```
LAN TCP/IP Setuphelp

IP Address:
192. 168. 0. 1

IP Subnet Mask:
255. 255. 255. 0

TICK - Use Router as DHCP Serverhelp

Starting IP Address:
192. 168. 0. 2

Ending IP Address:
192. 168. 0. 254
```

- > Address Reservation > Add
  >   cmd

```
ip address: 192.168.0.79
Mac adress: (This number will look something like 4c:a2:e0 etc.... - can by got by going to a website and typing whats my ip)
Device Name: (Right click my computer > properties) MYCOMPUTERNAME
```

- > Security > Firewall Rules > Outbound services > Edit

```
Service: http: tcp 80
action: allow always
access from: any
0 0 0 0
```

- > Security > Firewall Rules > Inbound services > Edit

```
Service: http: tcp 80
action: allow always
Destination IPv4 LAN address: 192.168.0.79
access from: any
```

## step 3 - create a docker container (ie jenkins), that will default to localhost, and expose the port on something other than 80, ie 81. (We need 80, to be exposed via our router)

- Create docker container on localhost:81

```
docker run -p 81:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name myjenkins -v %cd%/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins
```

## step 4 - Create a node server or equivalent that will proxy the exposed ip address to this localhost

- Create a proxy server that redirects 192.168.0.79 to localhost:81

```
import express from 'express';
import httpProxy from 'http-proxy';

const app = express();

const host = '192.168.0.79' ;
const port = '80';

const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.all('/*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('redirecting to docker container - http://localhost:81');
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: 'http://localhost:81'});
});


app.listen(port, host, function() {
  console.log('listening on ', host, ':', port);
});
```

## step 5 - type into a webbrowser  - whats my ip

ipv4 will by something like 30.132.323.11
Now type this into a webbrowser and you should see your docker container exposed via the node server proxy.